# how to delete session storage when changing the toggle state?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I wrote a function in jquery using toggleClass. The function is called with a button. I managed to save its result in session storage, so when refreshing the page the dark contrast on the page is saved. The problem occurs when I switch back to toggle state. Then session storage automatically loads the previous setting and as a result I still have the dark contrast on. I tried to write this script in two other ways to make it work properly, but unfortunately without positive result. If any of you will be able to help me, I will be very grateful. I've been trying to understand this for several hours.

My JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var state = sessionStorage.getItem("toggleState");
    if(state == "true"){
        $('*').not('div.container *').toggleClass("black-contrast");             
        $('header').toggleClass("black-contrast-border");
        $('img, div.container').toggleClass("overlay");
    }

    $('#black-contrast').click(function(){
        $('*').not('div.container *').toggleClass("black-contrast");             
        $('header').toggleClass("black-contrast-border");
        $('img, div.container').toggleClass("overlay");
    });
});
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('*').not('div.container *').toggleClass(sessionStorage.toggled);
    $('#black-contrast').on('click',function(){
        if (localStorage.toggled != "black-contrast" ) {
            $('*').not('div.container *').toggleClass("black-contrast", true );
            localStorage.toggled = "black-contrast";
        } else {
            $('*').not('div.container *').toggleClass("black-contrast", false );
            localStorage.toggled = "";
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with the onclick callback function
You are not toggling the `sessionStorage.toggleState`

You need to toggle the sessionstorage.toggleState each time user click the button.

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                               
    var state = sessionStorage.getItem("toggleState");                         
    if (state == "true") {                                                     
        $('*').not('div.container *').toggleClass("black-contrast");            
        $('header').toggleClass("black-contrast-border");                      
        $('img, div.container').toggleClass("overlay");                        
    }                                                                          
                                                                               
    $('#black-contrast').click(function() {                                    
        const state = sessionStorage.getItem("toggleState");                   
        state ? sessionStorage.removeItem("toggleState") : sessionStorage.setItem("toggleState");
        $('*').not('div.container *').toggleClass("black-contrast");            
        $('header').toggleClass("black-contrast-border");                      
        $('img, div.container').toggleClass("overlay");                        
    });                                                                        
});
```

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem! Thank you very much for your help. Despite the solution, unfortunately, the explanation is not entirely clear and understandable to me.

Comment: I just had to correct your code in one place, because there was a bug in the missing second argument of ```setItem("toggleState", "true");```

Comment: You are basically toggling the mode but you are faild to toggle that in sessionStorage. Here in the answer code we check for were the state is set or not. state ? sessionStorage.removeItem("toggleState") : sessionStorage.setItem("toggleState");